# Can't set From using mail command in bash

Tags: bash, email, postfix-mta, mutt, mailx

I am at my wits end....

All I want to do is set the From using a command line mail in a script.

I have tried mutt, mail, mailx...

Here is on command I tried:

`echo "Once again" | mail -s "Maybe this time" -A file.csv stevec@isonas.com -r 'John <john@company.com>' -a From:John\<john@company.com\>`

And another:

```
mutt -e "set from=john@company.com"...
```

And another:

```
mutt -e "set from=john@company.com" -e "set realname=John"
```

My `/etc/mailname` has the name I want too. I also tried configuring a muttrc file and that doesn't work

And another try:

```
mailx -r "DoNotReply@company.com" -a "From:DoNotReply@company.com" -s "Subject" -A "/opt/file.csv" "john@anothercompnay.com" <<< Some Text
```

Any ideas I can try?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have configured `john@company.com` in an extra configuration file (`~/.mutt/accounts/john`) which you usually source as soon as you start using it in `mutt`. Simply load that configuration.

```
echo "mail body" | mutt -e "source ~/.mutt/accounts/john" -e "set content_type=text/plain" -s "subject" -- peter@company.com
```

An account specific configuration file may look like this (`msmtp` is used in this case to send mails):

```
set sendmail        = "/usr/bin/msmtp -a Mailbox"
set realname        = "John"
set from            = "john@company.com"
set mbox_type       = Maildir
set folder          = "/home/john/.mails"
set spoolfile       = "+Mailbox/INBOX"
set record          = "+Mailbox/Sent"
set postponed       = "+Mailbox/Drafts"
```

Comment: That's new to me. What are the contents of that config file? I thought maybe like the muttrc but that doesn't seem to do it.

Comment: Added example configuration to answer.

Comment: Thanks for that. Still doesn't work though. Unless there are more ideas I'll just keep banging away at it.

Comment: How do you configured john@company.com?

Comment: As you suggested in your example.